# JOptionpane is showing on server machine only

Tags: java, swing, servlets, response, joptionpane

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Account already Exist !!", "Signup", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8084/app/index.html");
```

I wrote above code in servlet.

First problem :

I'm getting dialogbox in local machine but after dialog box, page is not redirecting to `index.html`. I mean it remain on same screen.

Second problem :

When I'm trying to access my app from different machine using ip address like `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/app/index.html`. In that case dialog box showing on server machine not in client machine.

Please help me to solve these problem. Also, dialog box always showing behind the browser, is there any way, it will show in front browser screen ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using Swing JdialogBox which is standalone and can not be used on web apps.
if you need to show any dialog box for client then better use Javascript alert like below

```
function x()
{
alert("user account already exists");
}
```

see this how javascript alert works

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff948/)

Comment: *"This is because you are using Swing JdialogBox which is standalone and can not be used on web apps"* Technically not true, but still a fair point ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer May i know why it is not technically not correct.

Comment: Applets ;) Yes I know The OP is running through a servlet, but your generalised ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Java Swing` Components in `Servlet.`

Instead, you could show an `Javascript Alert`

```
//servlet code
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
response.setContentType("text/html");  
out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
out.println("alert('User Account already Exist !!');");  
out.println("</script>");
```

**EDIT (I have tried myself and it works)**

**My Servlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class JavaScriptAlertServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JavaScriptAlertServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("alert('User Account already Exist !!');");
        out.println("</script>");
    }

}
```

[image: Proof of working]

Comment: This should work. Debug with Firebug and see if there is any Javascript error.